# Is there a built-in function to inverse Thread?

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation, inverse

Namely, while

```
Thread @ f[{a, b}, {x, y}]
```

gives

```
{f[a, x], f[b, y]}
```

the *InverseThread* (if it existed) should reverse the process that

```
InverseThread @ {f[a, x], f[b, y]}
```

gives

```
f[{a, b}, {x, y}]
```

Comment: `Thread[{f[a, x], f[b, y]}, f]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's make this a little more challenging:

```
invThread[body : _[h_[___] ..]] :=
  Replace[Thread[body, h], _[x_ ..] :> x, {1}]

f[{a, b}, {x, y}, z];
% // Thread
% // invThread
```

> ```
> {f[a, x, z], f[b, y, z]}
>
> f[{a, b}, {x, y}, z]
> ```