# Is there an easy way to extract data?Inverse function of Thread

Tags: functions, expression-manipulation

I want to learn some tips to deal data.
If i want connect two data with `Rule`.

```
a = Array[Sqrt, 10]; b = Array[Sin, 10];
Thread[a -> b]
```

Then i gets.

```
{1 -> Sin[1], Sqrt[2] -> Sin[2], Sqrt[3] -> Sin[3], 2 -> Sin[4], 
 Sqrt[5] -> Sin[5], Sqrt[6] -> Sin[6], Sqrt[7] -> Sin[7], 
 2 Sqrt[2] -> Sin[8], 3 -> Sin[9], Sqrt[10] -> Sin[10]}
```

I want to extract the result.That means an inverse function of Thread.

That is`Fun[Thread[a -> b]]->{a,b}`.
I know a solution is `a=d[[;;,1]];b=d[[;;,2]]`.
Is there a better?

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(130093)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130093/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Thread` a second time:

```
a = Array[Sqrt, 10]; b = Array[Sin, 10];
x = Thread[a -> b];

{aa, bb} = List @@ Thread[x, Rule];

aa === a
bb === b
```

> ```
> True
>
> True
> ```

Or a bit more concisely, but perhaps not in the spirit you seek:

```
{aa, bb} = Thread[List @@@ x];
```

Comment: I find a strange thing.
```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];  
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];  
fe[image_] := ImageData[image] // Flatten;
{a, b} = Thread[List @@@ trainingData ];
trainingData1 = Thread[(fe/@a) -> b]
```  
It needs lots of memories and will not stop.

Answer (score 6):

You'll get lots of variants. I always use `Part` like in your example. However one way, different to above, admittedly not an "UnThread" is:

```
{a, b} = Transpose[x /. Rule -> List]
```